# Add action dynamically to commandButton

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I am using JSF 2.0 and tomahawk-lib to create html elements dynamically. I want to add an action command to a HtmlCommandButton, but cannot get it done. Thanks in advance for your help. I can see the button and onclick gets triggered, so there must be a mistake related to the method expression.

```
HtmlCommandButton submitLogin = new HtmlCommandButton();
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext ctx = fc.getELContext();
String expression = "#{hangmanController.login}";
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[0];
MethodExpression me = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().
     createMethodExpression(ctx, expression, String.class, parameterTypes);
submitLogin.setActionExpression(me);
submitLogin.setOnclick("alert('BP');");
```

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically created `UIInput` and `UICommand` components must have a fixed ID set, otherwise JSF would during apply request values phase not be able to identify the request parameter associated with the input and command component in the request parameter map.

```
submitLogin.setId("submitLogin");
```